# Following required service principals [ec2.amazonaws.com] were not found in the trust relationships / AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have EKS cluster

```
{
    "cluster": {
        "name": "cluster",
        "arn": "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:xxx:cluster/cluster",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-04T18:24:38.786000-07:00",
        "version": "1.23",
        "endpoint": "https://xxx.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/eksrole",
        "resourcesVpcConfig": {
            "subnetIds": [
                "subnet-08f0fc71",
                "subnet-53032a18"
            ],
            "securityGroupIds": [],
            "clusterSecurityGroupId": "sg-06fa1aa90566a372e",
            "vpcId": "vpc-0e09ba76",
            "endpointPublicAccess": true,
            "endpointPrivateAccess": false,
            "publicAccessCidrs": [
                "0.0.0.0/0"
            ]
        },
        "kubernetesNetworkConfig": {
            "serviceIpv4Cidr": "10.100.0.0/16",
            "ipFamily": "ipv4"
        },
        "logging": {
            "clusterLogging": [
                {
                    "types": [
                        "api",
                        "audit",
                        "authenticator",
                        "controllerManager",
                        "scheduler"
                    ],
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "identity": {
            "oidc": {
                "issuer": "https://oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/18BD011EE7130A4BA313C555E62FB9FA"
            }
        },
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        xxx
        },
        "platformVersion": "eks.2",
        "tags": {}
    }
}
```

It has 1 node group which I added in UI (my account shown in UI `arn:aws:iam::xxx9399:user/user`)

```
aws eks list-nodegroups --cluster-name cluster
{
    "nodegroups": [
        "node-group"
    ]
}
```

I have no problems adding more node groups to the same cluster in UI, but when I use AWS CLI I get this error:

```
aws eks create-nodegroup --cluster-name cluster --nodegroup-name NG --subnets subnet-08f0fc71 subnet-53032a18 --node-role arn:aws:iam::xxx9399:role/aws-service-role/eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateNodegroup operation: Following required service principals [ec2.amazonaws.com] were not found in the trust relationships of nodeRole arn:aws:iam::xxx9399:role/aws-service-role/eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup
```

I checked AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SharedSecurityGroupRelatedPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/eks": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EKSCreatedSecurityGroupRelatedPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/eks:nodegroup-name": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "LaunchTemplateRelatedPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteLaunchTemplate",
                "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplateVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/eks:nodegroup-name": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AutoscalingRelatedPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:DeleteAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
                "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
                "autoscaling:PutNotificationConfiguration",
                "autoscaling:EnableMetricsCollection"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:*:*:autoScalingGroupName/eks-*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAutoscalingToCreateSLR",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                }
            },
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowASGCreationByEKS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:CreateOrUpdateTags",
                "autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "eks",
                        "eks:cluster-name",
                        "eks:nodegroup-name"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPassRoleToAutoscaling",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPassRoleToEC2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                        "ec2.amazonaws.com.cn"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PermissionsToManageResourcesForNodegroups",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplate",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
                "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:GetConsoleOutput",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PermissionsToCreateAndManageInstanceProfiles",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile",
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:instance-profile/eks-*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PermissionsToManageEKSAndKubernetesTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "eks",
                        "eks:cluster-name",
                        "eks:nodegroup-name",
                        "kubernetes.io/cluster/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It shows the following Trusted entities

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I cannot add anything to Trust Relationships (entities are not editable)
[image]

I also have AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup Policy with attached AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup role to it

```
aws iam get-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup
{
    "Policy": {
        "PolicyName": "AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup",
        "PolicyId": "ANPAZKAPJZG4KH2AAMJJG",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup",
        "Path": "/aws-service-role/",
        "DefaultVersionId": "v6",
        "AttachmentCount": 1,
        "PermissionsBoundaryUsageCount": 0,
        "IsAttachable": true,
        "Description": "Permissions required for managing nodegroups in the customer's account. These policies related to management of the following resources: AutoscalingGroups, SecurityGroups, LaunchTemplates and InstanceProfiles.",
        "CreateDate": "2019-11-07T01:34:26+00:00",
        "UpdateDate": "2022-01-14T00:33:26+00:00",
        "Tags": []
    }
}
```

But I cannot attach it to my user
[image]

I would like to know what actions I need to perform to

- be able to create a managed node group
- add required service principals [ec2.amazonaws.com] in the trust relationships of nodeRole arn:aws:iam::xxx9399:role/aws-service-role/eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com` to `ec2.amazonaws.com` in the permissions. At least that was my problem.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com" // change to ec2.amazonaws.com
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```